# How to check nth char of a string is a number with js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In javascript can we check nth character is a number using regular expressions without just using if conditions?

Comment: I think you are looking for `isNaN(parseInt("YOURSTRING".charAt(POSITION)));`

Comment: `/\d/.test(str.charAt(index))`

Comment: @Shubham— [*isNaN*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-isnan-number) converts the argument to Number, there's no need for *parseInt*.

Comment: @RobG I'll keep this in mind. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and take the negated value.

```js
console.log(!isNaN('123'[1])); // true, is number
console.log(!isNaN('1a3'[1])); // false, is not a number
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\d` regex to test against array index.

```js
var a = 'abc1def';

console.log(/\d/.test(a[3]))
console.log(/\d/.test(a[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a utility function and pass it the nth character to be checked, like so:

```
var fn = function(str, n) {
    return /\d/.test(parseInt(str[n]));
};
```

Now, you can simply call this function for any string and check any character position if it is a number.